# Set values for a HTMLCollection based on key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following where I am setting values based on index.

`children` in this case are of type `HTMLCollection`.

The following works fine but finding it to be not very readable and tightly coupled to index.

Is there a way I could use key instead to set values?

```
// what I have currently
const myRef = React.useRef();
myRef.current.children[0].value = 'apple';
myRef.current.children[1].value = 'orange';
myRef.current.children[2].value = 'pear';
myRef.current.children[3].value = 'mango';
```

Could I use key, something like how we would do it with a map.

```
myRef.current.children['some key one'] = 'apple';
myRef.current.children['some key two'] = 'orange';
myRef.current.children['some key three'] = 'pear';
myRef.current.children['some key four'] = 'mango';
```

Comment: You can do exactly that.

Comment: Better than that would be utilizing React's render cycle/state management to update content instead of refs.